# PHP Mailer user who fills in gets copy

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I made a contact form with PHPmailer but what i'm trying to do is, the person who fills in the contactform gets a copy of what he filled in, on his email. And that "email" is the email that he filled in, in field "email". (if that makes any sense).

Can u guys help me out? Here is my code.

**HTML/PHP**

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once 'helpers/security.php';

$errors = isset($_SESSION['errors']) ? $_SESSION['errors'] : [];
$fields = isset($_SESSION['fields']) ? $_SESSION['fields'] : [];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Contact form</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contact">

    <?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <?php echo implode('</li><li>', $errors); ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php  endif; ?>
    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
        <label>
            Your name*
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" <?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? 'Value="' . e($fields['name']) . '"' : '' ?>>
        </label>
        <label>
            Your email address *
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off" <?php echo isset($fields['email']) ? 'Value="' . e($fields['email']) . '"' : '' ?>>
        </label>
        <label>
            Your message *
            <textarea name="message" id="contact" rows="8"><?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : '' ?></textarea>
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Send">

        <p class="muted">* Means a required field</p>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
unset($_SESSION['errors']);
unset($_SESSION['fields']);
?>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once "libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

$errors = [];

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])) {

$fields = [
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    "message" => $_POST['message']
];

foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
    if(empty($data)){
        $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
    }
}

    // 587 is voor uitgaande email deze is SSL en SMTP.ziggo.nl
    // 993 is voor inkomende email deze is TLS en IMAP.ziggo.nl
    // 110 is voor inkomende email deze is POP3 en
if(empty($errors)){
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail->Host = '';
    $mail->Username = '';
    $mail->Password = '';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->isHTML();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

    $mail->Subject = 'Dit is een test voor birsken.nl Negeer dit';
    $mail->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' ('. $fields['email'] .')<p>'. $fields['message'] .'</p>';

    $mail->FromName = $fields['name'];
    $mail->AddAddress('', '');

    if($mail->send()){
        header('Location: bedankt.php');
        die();
    } else {
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo; exit;
    }
}

} else {
$errors[] = 'Something went wrong.';
}

$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
$_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;

header('location: index.php');
```

Comment: `$mail->AddAddress($fields['email'], '');`?

Comment: An validation email... I dont really know how to explain it better.

Comment: That's not doing it @u_mulder

Comment: `$mail->AddAddress('', '');` is pointless and you're not setting a From address (which should be your own address, not the submitter's). It looks like you've based your code on an obsolete example too - make sure you're using latest PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

You can CC and BCC according to PHPMailer docs:

```
$mailer->AddBCC("foo@gmail.com", "test");
$mailer->AddCC("something@gmail.com", "bla");
```

Comment: That doesnt work. I just give's me this error. http://prntscr.com/d2z4hm

Comment: @RainierLaan did you use `$mail->AddBCC("foo@gmail.com", "test");` (your variable is `$mail` as opposed to `$mailer` in the examples above)?

Comment: I tried this, `$mail->AddCC($fields['email'], $fields['name']);` But it doesnt work. The email that i filled in doesnt get a copy